# Heat Equation in Cylindrical Coordinates: Sinularity at r = 0 & Neumann Boundary Conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

I'm using the Explicit Euler method to find numerical approximations to the following laser heat equation in cylindrical coordinates. The laser is aimed at the point $r = 0$, the center of the cylinder. Due to symmetry, there is no dependence on angle:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} T(r,z,t)=
\kappa
\left (
\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial r^2} +
\frac{\partial T}{r \partial r} +
\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial z^2}
\right ) +
\frac{1}{\rho c}S(r,z,t)
$$

My first question is, how do I deal with the singularity at the boundary, $r = 0$?
This [paper](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/journals/Journal-of-Biomedical-Optics/volume-11/issue-3/034031/Temperature-distribution-in-selective-laser-tissue-interaction/10.1117/1.2204615.full?SSO=1) claims $\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial r^2} \approx \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial T}{\partial r} \approx 0$ at $r=0$, But this doesn't make sense to me for two reasons:


$1)$ Intuitively, if there's a heat source at $r = 0$ the heat should dissipate outward, therefore $\frac{\partial T}{\partial r} < 0$ at $r=0$.


$2)$ If we take $\frac{\partial T}{\partial r} < 0$ at $r=0$ to be true and discretize accordingly, there will be no information shared between $T(0,z,t)$ and $T(1,z,t)$. We end up with the nonsensical situation where if $T(0,z,t) = 0^{\circ}K$ and $T(1,z,t)=100^{\circ}K$, then $T(0,z,t+1) = 0^{\circ}K$.


Am I missing something? Is the paper wrong? Am I wrong? How do I deal with this $r=0$ singularity?


My second question is how do you discretize the heat equation with Neumann Boundary conditions $\frac{\partial T}{\partial z} = 0$ at $z=0$? The original heat equation does not have a $\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}$ term, so how do I incorporate it into a Forward Euler discretization? I'm having a hard time finding a good resource.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The claim seems to be made in terms being that over the distance used the temperature is constant so all derivatives disappear

Comment: Concerning the first question: You assume that your system is radially symmetric, which also means that the heat source is centered in the middle. That means that all the heat flow has to go outwards, else the system would not be symmetric. Also it follows that $\partial_rT=0\forall r=0$, but that does not have to be true outside the center.